# Dont know how to get mod_rewrite working in wampserver 2.5

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wampserver

Below is my .htaccess file code

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^settings$ settings.php [L]
```

Removed `#` from `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` in the httpd.conf file.

I checked from **wampmanager menu** that `mod_rewrite` is enabled, there is a tick mark beside `rewrite_module`, means mod_rewrite is **enabled**.

Restarted wampserver several times, but still it is going to a 404 page, if I add `.php` extension then it works fine.

Any suggestions please.

Comment: Delete cache of your browser and then check. please also check on other browser

Comment: Did you set `AllowOverride All` in apache config file ?

Comment: Thanks for reply. yes I set `AllowOverride All` to each occurance, and cleared browser cache. But still same

Comment: are you sure about `RewriteBase /` is okay please check where you applying the rule

Comment: What folder is you site located in.

Comment: @RiggsFolly **C:\wamp\www\DigitalEngine\** is the folder where my project is located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this .htaccess in DigitalEngine directory and try

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^settings$ settings.php [L]
```